# Symfony 3 with composer Bootstrap 3.3.6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, twig, symfony

Yesterday, I have installed `Bootstrap v3.3.6` by using `Composer` to add `Bootstrap` in my `Symfony` project. Now i have it in my `Symfony3` project but I can't use it because I tried all paths from my twig file but it doesn't find the file.

Are there some options I have to modify or something like that?

Comment: how can i modify the question ?

Comment: My bad, ignore that.

Comment: oh thanks, if you have solution for me ! :p

Comment: Duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453039/what-is-the-correct-way-to-add-bootstrap-to-a-symfony-app/42648116#42648116 - See my answer there on how to use the bootstrap from twig without bower, grunt or any other frontend tools, also without any intermediate bootstrap-bundle, just using the assetic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to add bootstrap to a symfony app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453039/what-is-the-correct-way-to-add-bootstrap-to-a-symfony-app)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your css/js/fonts/img folder in your web directory.

In your code, calling something like that should work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

Comment: yes but i add bootstrap with composer to have the possibility to have updates automatically so if i put files in my web directory, i will not have updates ?

Comment: In this case, maybe you can take a look at [bower](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/frontend/bower.html)