# What is the correct way to add bootstrap to a symfony app?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twig, composer-php, symfony

I'm using symfony framework 3 to develop a web application. I need to add boostrap's functionality to my application. I installed bootstrap using the below command. (I'm using composer.)

```
composer require twbs/bootstrap
```

It installs bootstrap to the application's vendor folder. More specifically `vendor\twbs\bootstrap`.

I need to attach bootstrap's `css` and `js` files in the application's twig templates (located in `app\Resources\views`) as assets.

e.g.:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But assets only work with files located in the web (`web\bundles\framework`) folder. I can copy those `.css` and `.js` files from the vendor folder to web folder manually to make this work but there should be a proper way to do it (i.e.: to add assets). e.g.: A command with `bin/console`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Symfony Best Practies gives the answer for this Problem: https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#web-assets

> If you are developing an application like this, you should use the tools that are recommended by the technology, such as Bower and GruntJS. You should develop your frontend application separately from your Symfony backend (even separating the repositories if you want).

In our project we use grunt to build and concat those files into the web-folder.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like that this no longer works in Symfony3.

In Symfony3 the following should work:

```
twig:
    form_themes: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']
```

Comment: This ensures that forms are created with bootstrap classes and other attributes, but we have to attach the bootstrap files by ourselves.

Answer (score 5):

The suggested approach [changed](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html) since Symfony version 4: Webpack Encore is used with npm / yarn for bundling the CSS and JavaScript resources, where the Bootstrap framework can be included.

Start by [installing Encore](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html) and follow with [the Bootstrap-specific documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/bootstrap.html). In summary, the following commands have to be performed:

```
composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
yarn install
yarn add bootstrap --dev

# after making the required changes to webpack.config.js, app.js, run Encore
yarn encore dev --watch
```

Comment: That is the correct way of adding Bootstrap to Symfony 4.* app

Comment: What version are you using @FabianoLothor?

Comment: Symfony Version 5

Answer (score 3):

Since Symfony v2.6 includes a new form theme designed for **Bootstrap 3** [oficial documentation](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme)

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form:
        resources: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']
        # resources: ['bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig']
```

Comment: Is the same true for symphony **3**?

Comment: Yes, the difference between sf3 and sf2.8 (latest LTS) is that in symfony 3 doesn't have the deprecated calls that sf2.8 has.
Why I recive "-1" puntuation?

Comment: Thanks, and I didn't you give -1. I gave +1, now. :)

Comment: **Doesn't work!** 

`[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]`

`Unrecognized option "form" under "twig"`

Answer (score 3):

From this link https://coderwall.com/p/cx1ztw/bootstrap-3-in-symfony-2-with-composer-and-no-extra-bundles (and changing `twitter`for `twbs`) this is what I have in my `config.yml`:

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        jsqueeze: ~
        scssphp:
            formatter: 'Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Compressed'
    assets:
        jquery:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.js
        bootstrap_js:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
        bootstrap_css:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css
            filters: [ cssrewrite ]
        bootstrap_glyphicons_ttf:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"
        bootstrap_glyphicons_eot:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"
        bootstrap_glyphicons_svg:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg"
        bootstrap_glyphicons_woff:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
```

I do have other dependencies in my `composer.json` like `jsqueeze` for example, or Leafo's scss processor, among `jquery` and more. I have this in my composer file:

```
    "components/font-awesome": "^4.7",
    "components/jquery": "^3.1"
    "leafo/scssphp": "^0.6.7",
    "patchwork/jsqueeze": "^2.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "^3.3",
```

I then use it like this for the css:

```
{% stylesheets
    '@bootstrap_css'
    'my/other/scss_file1.scss'
    'my/other/scss_file2.scss'

    filter='scssphp,cssrewrite'
    output='css/HelloTrip.css' %}

    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

{% endstylesheets %}
```

and for the javascripts, place `jquery` first:

```
{% javascripts
    '@jquery'
    '@bootstrap_js'
    'my/other/js_file1.js'
    'my/other/js_file2.js'

    filter='?jsqueeze'
    output='js/HelloTrip.js' %}

    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>

{% endjavascripts %}
```

I then use `bin/console assetic:dump` to compile all my assets.

Hope to help!

Comment: This is a great answer for Symfony2, but is no longer appropriate for the Symfony 3 version the question is asking about.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, the symlinks could be created automatically upon packages update. For example, in `composer.json` add new command in `"post-update-cmd"`:

```
// ...
"scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts",
            "rm web/bootstrap && ln -s -r `pwd`/vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/ web/bootstrap"
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a very simple approach...

```
$ composer request twbs/bootstrap
```

In composer.json...

```
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts",
        "@copy-bootstrap"
    ],
    "copy-bootstrap": [
        "bash copy-bootstrap.sh"
    ]
```

Where copy-bootstrap.sh contains...

```
mkdir -p public/static/bootstrap
cp -R vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist public/static/bootstrap
```

*Important!  If on windows make sure line endings in .sh file are LF instead of CRLF*

Then...

```
$ composer update
```

Now in base.html.twig...

```
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link href="static/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endblock %}

    {% block javascripts %}
        <script src="static/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    {% endblock %}
```

In index.html.twig...

```
{% block body %}
<div class="container m-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 border border-dark border-3">
            <h4>1st Row 2 Col</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 border border-dark border-3">
            <h4>1st Row 4 Col</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 border border-dark border-3">
            <h4>1st Row 6 Col</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 border border-dark border-3">
            <h4>2nd Row 4 Col</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 border border-dark border-3">
            <h4>2nd Row 6 Col</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 border border-dark border-3">
            <h4>2nd Row 2 Col</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Which produces this...

[image: Bootstrap grid example]